# LeanFT and test in multiple browsers

Tags: java, junit, leanft

I am new to LeanFT and JUnit, [LeanFT docs](http://leanft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/14.00/JavaSDKReference/index.html) doesn't  shed much light on how to use it.

I need to run my test, written in JUnit/MeanFT mesh, in more than one browser.

Now it looks like this:

```java
@Test
    public void testverify_Startsida() throws GeneralLeanFtException, Exception {

        //Open browser
        Browser browser = BrowserFactory.launch(BrowserType.CHROME);
```

The docs says that BrowsterType can be an array of browsers, but I havn't figured out how, all my tries ends in crash and burn.

I might be embarising myself with this but hey youre nice guys and all. :)

Comment: "All my tries ends in crash and burn". Could you please provide more details. What exactly did you try and what error messages were? Ideally post a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: May be [parametrized tests](https://github.com/junit-team/junit/wiki/Parameterized-tests) can help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I'm in a position to answer your query. Few months back I was in the same position as yours. I banged my head while trying to get multi-threading going in leanft. For the record, LeanFT does not support multi-threading(check out the FAQ section [here](http://leanft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/latest/HelpCenter/Content/HelpCenterRoot/FAQ.htm)).

But I have figured out a sort of work-around to get LeanFT going on multiple machines with a small help from selenium. In one of my [blog post](https://learn2automate.wordpress.com/2015/12/16/leanft-c-tutorial-part-9-using-leanft-and-selenium-together/)(though its in C#, the core working in Java remains the same), I have mentioned how we can work with Selenium and LeanFT in one script(this can give you tremendous power since you can use best of both worlds).

So if you want to get multi-threading going, I would suggest you to launch multiple drivers from selenium and attach to those drivers by using the BrowserFactory.getAllOpenBrowsers() function in LeanFT. Do let me know if this helps.

Comment: Don't add signatures to your answers; they add undue noise to the actual answer.

Comment: It would also be a good idea to post some of the relevant bits from your blog post here, since we can't guarantee that your blog will remain up (but so long as someone's looking on *this* site, we know that it will be up).